# How to disable the browser context menu in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Is it possible to disable the context menu in qooxdoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every qooxdoo widget has a [nativeContextMenu property](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.core.Widget~nativeContextMenu). You can set it to false on the application root to prevent the browser context menu:

```
qx.core.Init.getApplication().getRoot().setNativeContextMenu(false);
```

Comment: It's usually less advantageous to link to "current" URLs on qooxdoo's web site, as they will change over time. A link like demo.qooxdoo.org/1.0/... will remain stable.